# Combine two matrix into a bigger matrix using CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to build a bigger matrix from smaller matrices using CUDA. My task is to, given two matrix, one matrix should be copied to the top and the second matrix should be copied to the bottom. When I tried, I could copy the top matrix but the bottom could not be copied (or gives unexpected results ie, 0). I don't want to change the number of blocks
Please help me

Here is my code and

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5
#define BLOCK_DIM 3

__global__ void matrixCombine (int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    int index = col + row * N;

    if (col < N && row < N)     //copying upper matrix is working
        c[index] = a[index];
    if (col >= N && row >= N)  //copying lower matrix is NOT working
        c[index] = b[index];
}

void printMatrix(int a[N][N] )
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printMatrixAns(int a[N][N] )
{
    for(int i=0; i<2*N; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
            printf("%d\t", a[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[N][N], b[N][N], c[2*N][N];
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;

    int size = N * N * sizeof(int);
    int sizeofc = 2 * N * N * sizeof(int);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
            a[i][j] = rand() % 256;
            b[i][j] = rand() % 256;
        }

    printf("Matrix A\n");
    printMatrix(a);
    printf("Matrix B\n");
    printMatrix(b);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, sizeofc);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_DIM, BLOCK_DIM);
    dim3 dimGrid((N+dimBlock.x-1)/dimBlock.x, (N+dimBlock.y-1)/dimBlock.y);

    printf("dimGrid.x = %d, dimGrid.y = %d\n", dimGrid.x, dimGrid.y);

    matrixCombine<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(dev_a,dev_b,dev_c);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, sizeofc, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("Matrix c\n");
    printMatrixAns(c);

    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your kernel, this:

```
int index = col + row * N;
if (col < N && row < N)     //copying upper matrix is working
    c[index] = a[index];
if (col >= N && row >= N)  //copying lower matrix is NOT working
    c[index] = b[index];
```

is wrong. Both `a` and `b` only have NxN elements, and `c` 2NxN elements, so that would result in out of bounds memory access in `b` and `c`, and you are only launching slightly more than NxN threads anyway, so there is no guarantee that the grid size would be enough to cover 2NxN output elements. If you are stacking `a` over `b` into a 2NxN matrix you want something like this:

```
c[row][col] = a[row][col]
c[row+N][col] = b[row][col]
```

with `row<N` and `col<N`. In code that might look like this for a grid of slightly more than `NxN`threads:

```
int index = col + row * N;

if (col < N && row < N) {
    c[index] = a[index];
    c[index + N*N] = b[index];
}
```

i.e. each thread copies an element of `a` and an element of `b` into `c`, with the `a` element written to `c[row][col]`, and the `b` element written to `c[row+N][col]`

Comment: @SaahithyanVigneswaran: If this answered your question, you can upvote and/or accept this answer, which will take your question off the list of unanswered questions and make the question and answer easier to find by search

Comment: Thank you, I tried to up vote, since I've less than 15 reputation, I couldn't vote